# mouse collision with angle in c language

Tags: c, math, angle

I did a mouse collision function that was working fine, until I decide to change the angle of the object. It detects the collision between the mouse and an "image" without angle.
What should I do if I want that function to work with angle.

```c
typedef struct ImagePropTag ImagePropSet;
struct ImagePropTag {
    vf2d * pos, *axis;
    BP32 angle;
    PixelSet * color;
    STATUS allocated;
};

typedef struct ImageTag ImageSet;
struct ImageTag {
    B32 id;
    B8 * path;
    B0 * data;
    B32 w, h;
    BP32 wz, hz;
    IMAGE_FLIP flip;
    IMAGE_MODE mode;
    ImageSet * preview, *next;
    STATUS (*next_first)(ImageSet ** p, ImageSet * n);
    STATUS (*next_last)(ImageSet ** p, ImageSet * n);
    ImageSet * (*search)(ImageSet * p, B32 id);
    STATUS (*clone)(ImageSet ** p1, ImageSet * p2);
    STATUS (*pixel_set)(ImageSet * i, B32 x, B32 y, PixelSet * p);
    B0 (*zoom_fit)(ImageSet * p, B32 w, B32 h);
    B0 (*draw)(ImageSet * p, ImagePropSet * ip, vf2d * scroll);
    B0 (*draw_map)(ImageSet * p, ImagePropSet * ip);
    STATUS (*pop)(ImageSet * p);
    STATUS (*destroy)(ImageSet * p);
};

MOUSE_OF_CALL STATUS MOUSE_OF_TYPE mouse_of_over(ImageSet * i, ImagePropSet * p){
    return machine && machine->mouse && i && p && p->pos && ((machine-mouse->x >= p->pos->x && machine->mouse->x <= p->pos->x + (i->w * i->wz)) &&  (machine->mouse->y >= p->pos->y && machine->mouse->y <= p->pos->y + (i->h * i->hz))) ? On : Off;
}

the_start(){
    ObjectSet o = object_of_start();
    for (o.id = AUDIO_MENU_BACK; o.id <= AUDIO_MENU_APPLY; o.id++){
        if (o.id == AUDIO_MENU_BACK) {
            o.name = "back";
            o.of->angle = 20;
        }
    }
}

the_update(){
    switch(...){
      case AUDIO_MENU_BACK: {
            writing(update);
            place->zoom_fit(update, place->machine->w * .195, place->machine->h * .05);
            place->position_set(update, place->machine->w * .047, (place->machine->h * .21) - place->height_get(update));
            if (place->mouse_over(update)){
                if (place->mouse_release(MACHINE_MOUSE_LEFT)){
                    place->audio_play(AUDIO_SPRITE_PRESS);
                    nameless->menu = OPTIONS_MENU;
                    B16_ON(nameless->status, PREPARE);
                }
                pixel_rgba_set(update->object->of->color, 255, 255, 255, 128);
            } else pixel_rgba_set(update->object->of->color, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

How can I verify the x and y of this given image if I change its angle.

[image]

This is the audio interface of my game. As you guys can see, the back and apply button have angle, and only can be detected if I point the mouse the
to the "straight" area.

The place->mouse_over is a pointer to the mouse_of_over function.

I'm sorry if I am making an obvious question for you. But it is very hard for me. Since now thanks

Comment: No, I am trying to do everything in my engine.

Comment: why tag [tag:c++] when you're using [tag:c]?

Comment: The most simple solution would be accepting a rectangle the buttons fit in entirely. If you cannot accept, then you'd still detect the collision with that rectangle but add additional checks; upper left and upper right form a straight line, just as lower left and lower right, your point needs to be below top line and above bottom line.

Comment: You might pre-calculate (UL.y - UR.y) / (UL.x - UR.x) as `slope` for not having to re-calculate with every check, then calculate (UL.y - P.y) / (UL.x - P.x), which must be equal or less than `slope` and (LL.y - P.y) / (LL.x - P.x), which must be equal or greater than `slope` – UL, UR, LL, LR correspond to upper/lower left/right corners.

Comment: If upper and lower slopes differ you need to calculate them separately, of course, and if slopes are not symmetric for both buttons you'd need to store both (pairs), otherwise right slope simply is -left slope.

Comment: Side note: You'll likely have to do the calculations in double or – to avoid floating point calculations – multiply the y-differences with e. g. 1024 and add half of the x-difference before division for improved rounding.

Comment: This up-left and up-right that you mean should be a Delta? Something like so? typedef struct DeltaSet{ float begin,end; }; DeltaSet x,y; (y.end - y.begin) / (x.end - x.begin). ?